# Java Date, string convert to Date Object

Tags: java

I have a question, how can I convert a string like `20130706123020` to a date object.
So I what to convert the string `20130706123020` to a date object looking like:

> 2013-07-06 12:30:20

Attempted code:

```
String date = "20130706234310";
Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-m-d H:m:s").parse(date);
System.out.println(date1);
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I have tried but I got the following error: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20130706234310"

Comment: i tried the SimpleDateFormat and DateTimeFormat

Comment: Post your attempted code, one of those date libs only

Comment: import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
 


public class Test {
 
    public static void main (String args[]) {

        
        try {
            String date = "20130706234310";
            Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-m-d H:m:s").parse(date);
            System.out.println(date1);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } 
 
}

Comment: 'yyyy-m-d-H:m:s' doesn't match the format of the string you are giving the date formatter so it won't parse it.  Make the format string match your format.

Comment: @Liviu Don't post your code as comment (it is hard to read). Instead add it to your question using [[edit]] option (right under your question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to first `parse` the `String` using the `parse` method from [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Then pass the `Date` object returned by the `parse` method to another `SimpleDateFormat` and then using the `format` method get the date in the format you want.

```
String s = "201307061230202";

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSS"); // format in which you get the String
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); // format in which you want the date to be in
System.out.println(sdf1.format(sdf.parse(s)));
```

The significance of `HH`, `hh`, `KK` and `kk` in the hour field is different. I have used `HH` you can use the one according to your requirement.

```
H   Hour in day (0-23)
k   Hour in day (1-24)
K   Hour in am/pm (0-11)
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)
```

Answer (score 1):

use this :

> long int my_date = 20130706123020L

and after that :

> String date_Text = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date(my_date));

Comment: This does not compile... `error: integer number too large: 20130706123020`

Comment: are you using "Long int " ?

Comment: Yes, if you change it to `long my_date = 20130706123020L;` it compiles. It looks like the compiler wants to interpret the number as an `int` if you omit the `L` in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss"); 
Date date = sdf.parse("20130706123020");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 

System.out.println(sdf2.format(date));
```